# Could not create task ':app:compileProdDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build

I have been developing an Android app using Kotlin in Android Studio.

I try to upgrade the Kotlin version to '1.9.0'

```
buildscript {

    ext {
        agp_version = '8.2.2'
        kotlinVersion = '1.6.21' // upgrade the Kotlin version to '1.9.0'
        jacocoVersion = '0.8.10'
    }
    
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://sdk.withpersona.com/android/releases'}
        maven { url "https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/cometchat/cometchat-pro-android/maven/"}
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$agp_version"
        classpath 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-gradle-plugin:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appdistribution-gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:$jacocoVersion"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.2'
    }
}
```

Here is my error when trying to sync gradle files:

```
A build operation failed.
    Could not create task ':app:compileProdDebugKotlin'.
Could not create task ':app:compileProdDebugKotlin'.
'org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceTask org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.source(java.lang.Object[])'
```